# Instagram Graph API pull, works but runs slow would like advice

Tags: javascript, performance, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I have written some code to pull image from instagram using the instagram graph api. Everything works fine but the performance is slow.
I am using JavaScript but had the same issue but worse with PHP. I am fairly new and inexperienced with this and any advice would be great.

Below is the code:

```
$.getJSON(instagram_url_1, function(data) {
    instagram_array_1 = data['data'];

    instagram_next = data['paging'];
    instagram_next = instagram_next['next'];

    for (var image_count = 0; image_count < 25; image_count++) {
      image_data = instagram_array_1[image_count];
      image_data = image_data['id'];
      image_link = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + image_data + '?fields=media_url&access_token=' + access_token;
      image_array[image_count] = image_link;
    };

    $.getJSON(instagram_next, function(data) {
      instagram_array_2 = data['data'];

      for (image_count = 0; image_count < 25; image_count++) {
        image_data = instagram_array_2[image_count];
        image_data = image_data['id'];
        image_link = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + image_data + '?fields=media_url&access_token=' + access_token;
        image_array[image_count + 25] = image_link;
      };

      console.log(image_array);

      for (var image_count = 0; image_count < 40; image_count++) {
        image_link_array = image_array[image_count];

        $.getJSON(image_link_array, function(data) {
          image_link = data['media_url'];
          image_html = '<img class="instagram-images" src=' + image_link + ' />';
          $('#instagram-body').append(image_html);
        });
      };
    });
  });
```

The website can take a little time to load, not ages but enough that I would like to try and streamline it to improve UX. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

- Don´t use this code on every page load, cache results server side to avoid API limits.
- Don´t hardcode Access Tokens on the client, they are always meant to be kept secret. Only use them on the server.
- **You are doing an API call for every single image, of course that´s super-slow. Better: `/instagram-id/media?fields=media_url` - just ONE call.**

Reference:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/media
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media